# Googlescripts mergesort

Tags: google-apps-script, mergesort

```
function MergeSort() {
var low = 1;
var mid = 2;
var high = 3;
var i, m, k, l; 
temp[MAX] = new array();
l = low;
i = low;
m = mid+1;

while( 1 < = mid && m <= high ) {
    if(array[1] < = arr[m]) {
        temp[i] = arr[1];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        temp[i] = arr[m];
        m++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  if(1>mid) {
      for(k=m;k<=high;k++){
          temp[i]=arr[k];
          i++;
      }
  }
  else {
      for(k=1;k<=mid;k++) {
      temp[i]=arr[k];
      i++;
  }
}

for(k=low;k<=high;k++) {
    arr[k]=temp[k];
}
```

}

Coming from another language I am totally clueless, could someone point me in the right direction for taking a set of numbers and putting them in order via mergeSort? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example for Merge sort.

```
var array = [5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6];


function merge(A, p, q, r){
   var n1 = q - p + 1;
   var n2 = r - q;
   var i = 0, j = 0, L = [], R = [];
   while (i < n1){
       L.push(A[p + i++]);
   }
   while(j < n2){
       R.push(A[q + j++ + 1]);
   }

   L.push(Number.MAX_VALUE);
   R.push(Number.MAX_VALUE);

   i = 0; 
   j = 0; 

   var k = p;
   while(k <= r){
       if(L[i] <= R[j]){
          A[k] = L[i];
          i = i + 1;
       }else{
          A[k] = R[j];
          j = j + 1;
   }
   k = k + 1;
}
}

function mergeSort(A, p, r){
if(p < r){
    var q = Math.floor((p + r) / 2);

    mergeSort(A, p, q); 
    mergeSort(A, q + 1, r);
    merge(A, p, q, r);
}
}

function testMergeSort(){
   var p = 0;
   var r = (array.length) - 1;
   Logger.log("BEFORE: " + array);
   mergeSort(array, p, r);
   Logger.log("AFTER: " + array);
 }
```

Hope that helps!